# how to use CKEditor 4.5.7 in a ASP.net project

Tags: ckeditor

i am highly confused why i cannot intergrate the latest version of CKEditor in a ASP.net website. Which coding technologies is the 4.5.7 version comapible with (ie: php/jsp/ect)?

Isnt CKEditor for any HTML page?

Currently the latest ASP.net version is 3.6 which lacks support from many new plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a quick test:

- download and decompress the .Net package from CKEdit site (3.6);
- download the latest version of the javascript files (4.5.7);
- check that the samples provided with the .Net package work fine;
- rename the ckeditor folder in the solution and copy the new one downloaded from the site;
- clean the solution and rebuild the projet, and check if it works fine;
- replace the occurrences of the "kama" skin to the newer "moono" as the former one is replaced by the other in the 4.x version;
- like this, it seems to be working just fine

Do you have specific issues I can look into?

HTH

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You add CKeditor.js javascript to your pages and call `CKEDITOR.replace('id-of-textarea-here');`

You don't need any ASP.NET specific packages.

Comment: is there a step-by-step example? or a sample implementation of this in a asp.net project you can point me to? I understand the `CKEDITOR.replace` piece but then not sure how i change my `C#` code that executes when i click the save button. How would i  access this editor in my asp.net C# code?

Comment: @codeNinja Like any other form, the textarea is submitted and should be available when you post