# How to integrate ckeditor in a razor page?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, ckeditor

I am looking to integrate ckeditor-full 4.14 into a razor page. I have downloaded the NuGet package into my project in Visual Studio. I cannot find any documentation on how to implement it into a .razor page. Can anyone help?

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLgyd.png)

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350456/how-to-use-ckeditor-4-5-7-in-a-asp-net-project

Comment: @azeem I am looking to add this to a razor page, not an HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

In razor page,we add scripts in  @section Scripts,you can add the script liking this:

```
<div>
<textarea id="textarea111"></textarea>
</div>
@section Scripts {
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.14.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ckeditor; 
    $(function () {
        ckeditor = CKEDITOR.replace("textarea111"); 
    });
</script>
}
```

And this is my result of the code.
[image]

Update:

In blazor pages:

Firstly, You can install from NuGet using the following command:

```
Install-Package Blazored.TextEditor
```

Next,in Pages/_Host.cshtml :

Add the following CSS in the head tag

```
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.bubble.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then add the JS script at the bottom of the page using the following script tag.

```
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/Blazored.TextEditor/quill-blot-formatter.min.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/Blazored.TextEditor/Blazored-BlazorQuill.js"></script>
```

And this is my page：

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@using Blazored.TextEditor
<div>
        <BlazoredTextEditor>
            <ToolbarContent>
                <select class="ql-header">
                    <option selected=""></option>
                    <option value="1"></option>
                    <option value="2"></option>
                    <option value="3"></option>
                    <option value="4"></option>
                    <option value="5"></option>
                </select>
                <span class="ql-formats">
                    <button class="ql-bold"></button>
                    <button class="ql-italic"></button>
                    <button class="ql-underline"></button>
                    <button class="ql-strike"></button>
                </span>
                <span class="ql-formats">
                    <select class="ql-color"></select>
                    <select class="ql-background"></select>
                </span>
                <span class="ql-formats">
                    <button class="ql-list" value="ordered"></button>
                    <button class="ql-list" value="bullet"></button>
                </span>
                <span class="ql-formats">
                    <button class="ql-link"></button>
                </span>
            </ToolbarContent>

            <EditorContent>
                <br />
                <h4>You can edit the text.</h4>

            </EditorContent>
        </BlazoredTextEditor>

    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: The problem I get when trying to add a script like the above to my razor page is an error that says "Script tags should not be placed in components because they cannot be updated dynamically". Do you know why yours allowed you to add a script and mine did not? I added a screenshot to my post to show you the error.

Comment: From the error of you,I find your page is blazor,blazor cannot use script directly,if you want to load the ckeditor,you can add the script in Pages/_Host.cshtml.And then your page can load it.However,you cannot use<script></script>in your page.So even you load it,you cannot use it in your page.Unless you do like [this](https://cpratt.co/blazor-rich-text-editor-using-ckeditor/).Wirte a js  to realize the ckeditor.And add the js in Pages/_Host.cshtml . Except this, you can also use rick text editor in blazor,I update my answer to show how to use the blazor rick  text editor.

Comment: I already have Blazored rich text editor implemented in my app, I was looking to use ckeditor since it has more options. It looks like thanks to your information that will not be possible. Thanks.